# Collection<string> vs ArrayList<string>

Tags: java

```
Collection<string> collection = new ArrayList<string>();
```

I noticed the above code is in fact the same as `ArrayList<string> collection = new ArrayList<string>();`

Would it mean I can have any name to replace the first Collection/ArrayList like

```
anyname<string> collection = new ArrayList<string>();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Collection is an interface which Arraylist implements that interface.

Comment: It's actually *not* in fact the same. It's distinctly different.

Answer (score 1):

You are able to do that because `ArrayList implements Collection`

```
Class ArrayList<E>

java.lang.Object
  java.util.AbstractCollection<E>
    java.util.AbstractList<E>
      java.util.ArrayList<E>

All Implemented Interfaces:
Serializable, Cloneable, Iterable<E>, Collection<E>, List<E>, RandomAccess
```

`---->` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` implements the interface `Collection` so **collection** can be cast to a `Collection`

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

and this tutorial on using Interfaces http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceAsType.html

Answer (score 0):

`Collection` is a interface, while `ArrayList` is one of the implementations of `Collection`.

Because `ArrayList --> List --> Collection`, so you can declare an `ArrayList` instance as `Collection`, `List` and `ArrayList`. Other types won't work.

Answer (score 0):

[why-define-a-java-object-using-interface-e-g-map-rather-than-implementation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/225674/why-define-a-java-object-using-interface-e-g-map-rather-than-implementation) I hope this will help you understand , why use an interface type rather than concrete implementation while initializing an object and storing it's reference to a type variable.

Answer (score -1):

With an `ArrayList` (that implements `Collection`) you are allowed to do this .